# Script name collision in terminal

Tags: macos, path, npm

I just installed

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

And attempted to initialize a new project

```
ng new foo
```

Unfortunately I already have nailgun installed which also uses the `ng` keyword.

How can I set which has precedence? Better yet, is there an easy way to rename one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one found in the path is the one that will be called, so you could re-order your path as a first option.  When you needed nailgun, you could swap the order for the nailgun and global npm modules directories in your path.

You *could* rename `ng` in the .bin directory in your global install location, but this could have side effects if other angular tools expect to be able to call `ng`.